# Trying to retrieve json value from json object in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json

I cannot retrieve the value which is in the "callingCodes" array with Android Studio. My code seems correct but I still have error messages.

Here is the json file:

```
[
  {
    "isoName": "AF",
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "currencyCode": "AFN",
    "currencyName": "Afghan Afghani",
    "currencySymbol": "؋",
    "flag": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rld-flags/af.svg",
    "callingCodes": [
      "+93"
    ]
  },
  {
    "isoName": "AL",
    "name": "Albania",
    "currencyCode": "ALL",
    "currencyName": "Albanian Lek",
    "currencySymbol": "Lek",
    "flag": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rld-flags/al.svg",
    "callingCodes": [
      "+355"
    ]
  },
  {
    "isoName": "DZ",
    "name": "Algeria",
    "currencyCode": "DZD",
    "currencyName": "Algerian Dinar",
    "currencySymbol": "د.ج.‏",
    "flag": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rld-flags/dz.svg",
    "callingCodes": [
      "+213"
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is my java android studio code:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String call = (String) data.getJSONArray("callingCodes").get(0);

                            countryOperatorList.add(new CountryOperator(
                                    data.getString("isoName"),
                                    data.getString("name"),
                                    data.getString("currencyCode"),
                                    data.getString("currencyName"),
                                    data.getString("currencySymbol"),
                                    data.getString("flag"),
                                    call

                            ));
                        }
```

I tried to convert the key "callingCode" into String but it returns it to as ["+93"] but I only want to recover '+93'.

But when I tried the above code I got this error message:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)
```

Which is thrown by this line of code:

```
String call = (String) data.getJSONArray("callingCodes").get(0);
```

Does anyone have a solution so that I can retrieve the value of the callingCode key.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change this on your code that is work fine with I recommend for you get value using
optJSONArray or optString this used return null if key not found
my snippet code is

```
try {
  JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject data = array.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray jsr =  data.optJSONArray("callingCodes");
    String call=null;
    if (jsr!=null&&!jsr.isNull(0)){
     // Log.e("value",jsr.optString(0));
      call = jsr.optString(0)
      }
   
   countryOperatorList.add(new CountryOperator(
                                data.getString("isoName"),
                                data.getString("name"),
                                data.getString("currencyCode"),
                                data.getString("currencyName"),
                                data.getString("currencySymbol"),
                                data.getString("flag"),
                                call

                        ));
  }

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro, it works successfully that's exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

is there any particular reason that you're doing the parsing yourself? Could you not use Json with an object? the example uses [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

so something like (example code is in Kotlin):

```
val data = Gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, List<YourJsonObject>)

data class YourJsonObject(
   val isoName: String,
   val name: String, 
   val name: String, 
   val currencyCode: String, 
   val currencyName: String, 
   val currencySymbol: String, 
   val flag: String, 
   val callingCodes: List<String>
)
```

Java example:

```
List<YourJsonObject> data = Gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, List<YourJsonObject>)

public class YourJsonObject {
   private String isoName;
   private String name;
   private String currencyCode;
   private String currencyName;
   private String currencySymbol;
   private String flag;
   private List<String> callingCodes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm not using Kotlin, I'm using JAVA.
This json api file is very important for app. The problem come frome "callingCodes" it's a key which contain a string array with no key.  If this table contained a key I was not going to have this problem.

Comment: the same can be done in Java, it's just a class, let me update with an example

Comment: @HorlyAndelo i've updated, please take a look, having a list of strings inside the `callingCodes` node should be perfectly fine, then once you have your object, you can access the list normally with `object.callingCodes.get(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works but for case if `callingCodes` are not empty. You must be sure that `callingCodes.length > 0` to invoke `array.get(0)` method.

You can use `array.optString(0)` that will return an empty string if callingCode doesn't exist.

Comment: I had tried this but it didn't work.
Thank you very much for your answer